# Photoshop: a steady stream of water coming out of showerhead with pressure

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I have been asked to edit an image of a showerhead, where the water looks in pic below
(i.e. a photo taken in very high shutter speed where the water flowing from the shower head looks like individual droplets):

[image: shower head]
Pic 1

**HOW DO I TRANSORM THE PIC ABOVE TO THE PIC BELOW???**

[image: shower head pressure]Pic 2

Now it looks like a steady stream of water coming out with pressure.This is my aim.

I also have a pic of a showerhead with no water coming out of it. Can i alter it to look like Pic 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop you could use **Motion Blur**.

Duplicate your image and go to Filter -> Blur -> Motion Blur. Set the angle that will go along with the arc of the water, Angle at 23° and a distance of !30 is pretty close. You want to create the blur effect that would be seen from a slow shutter speed but still keep some detail.

Lower the opacity of the blur layer, this will allow some detail on the underlining layer.

I would also add a ripple effect to the blur layer, go to Filter -> Distort -> Ripple. You want to pick a setting that gives the blur layer some jagged edges.

Then add an layer mask to the blur layer and hide the shower head and part of the water coming out of the shower head.

**Result**

[image: water effect result]